# avoid loss of data when back to the previous page in mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my page i have a two dropdownlist and 2 partial view. In that partial view i have lot of textbox and that textbox contains values that are entered by the user. So if i redirect this page to next page and use back button to get this page means i lost my partial view and its value. 
    I use the following techniques.

```
1) <input type="button" value="Back" class="btn" onclick="javascript:  
   window.history.back(-1);return false;" />
2) <input type="button" value="Back" class="btn" onclick="window.history.back();" />
3) <input type="button" value="Back" class="btn" onclick="window.history.go(-1);" />
```

but the fact is i loss my data while pressing the back button.
Please help me to solve this issue..

Comment: So, you are not posting the data on first page to server?

Comment: yeah i posted the data to the next page as a Querystring

Comment: When are you saving the form data? Where is submit button located? in the second page?

Comment: i not use submit button.. i use javascript function to call the controller action.. i'm not saving the form data

Answer (score 1):

You have to save this when you go to your next page and disable caching on that page with the data. When you click the back button, your page needs to check if any data needs to be loaded based on some user's session information that represents 'I've saved this already', otherwise they will lose the info. Ideally, you have some session identifier at this point so when the page loads it checks if data from your screen is available - if so load it, if not the form remains empty.
See more details here: [Dont break the back button](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2007/10/03/60-of-web-users-cant-be-wrong-dont-break-the-back-button/)